# mpirun on os X

Tags: macos, osx-leopard, mpi, openmpi

Is there a way to run a local mpi job locally on os X leopard(10.5.6) with more than 62 processes.  When I run the job with 62 processes, it dies

```
$mpirun -np 62 a.out 
mpirun noticed that job rank 0 with PID 0 on node Macintosh-001D4F4BC6BC.private exited on signal 15 (Terminated). 
60 additional processes aborted (not shown)
```

and when I run it with 61 processes it runs fine.

Comment: I'm noticing the same problem with an mpi hello world program. Signal 15 seems to be generic. My guess is that the mpi lib is terminating due to an OS limitation and not issuing a good error about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to my comment, I did some googling and I suspect that this is caused by a resource limit set by the OS. Also, the vicinity of the failure to a multiple 2 is suspicious. My best guess is that something in the mpi library (MPI_Send maybe) is spawning additional processes, which exceed the limit of 266 (see ulimit -a).

Comment: Looks to be correct.  I set the "ulimit -n 500" and that fixed it.

Comment: @Milhous How did you set `ulimit -n 500`? Is this when installing or running mpirun?

Comment: It would be when running mpirun.